# How do you get reputation points?

Tags: discussion

How do you get reputation points if you can't comment or interact with things till you have reputation points but you need reputation points to be able to comment and to get the point you ..... went cross eyed.

Comment: You can gain initial reputation by asking good questions or giving good answers. By good I basically mean, rewarded with an upvote or accepted as the answer to a question. It is an incentive to participate in the Q&A system as it is intended. So there is actually a purpose behind it. You might want to give the [help] a good read for more insight.

Answer (score 13):

You [get reputation points](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) for asking a good question and for giving good answers. This you can do immediately after creating an account. Once you've done some contributions you [gain the privilege](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) of commenting.

If anyone could comment just by opening an account, we would be flooded with spam.

Comment: The "good" questions have already mostly been asked.  I find in development that I don't need to re-ask questions, just find the information source and will find an answer.  Seldom do I see that I have to ask a question because I am the only person in the World that is having that particular issue...

With that said, all I really want to do is be able to upvote or downvote somebody elses answer based on it's correctness, etc.  And, possibly, occasionally, leave an explanatory comment.  I guess my answer has been provided and I will answer other people's questions.

Comment: And it says you have to have 5 reputation points just do answer in WordPress Meta.  So, slim is getting slimmer.  Guess I need to make up some questions....

Comment: I would disagree that all the "good" questions have been asked. "Good" isn't a term applied to the quality of the question in and of itself, but rather are you asking for something with good detail and showing us what you already have tried and have some code to share with us. An example of a "bad" question would be something like "What plugin should I use to do X?"

Comment: @mrwpress every day there many new questions that you could answer in order to get reputation points.

Comment: Hi CJBJ.  Actually I can't.  I don't have 5 reputation points to be able to answer.

Comment: belinus,  my point was 99.99% of the time I can find someone that has asked whatever question I would be asking and find the answer.  So why would I have to re-post it just to reword it as MY question?  The point is the question has usually been asked.  And the answer is usually there for you to find it.  If I come across a question that I see nobody has ever asked (highly unlikely) then I will post it....

Comment: @mrwpress Yes you can. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-posts

Comment: @mrwpress Then that's great that it's already been asked! Saves you having to post it and wait for an answer yourself... right? What's the main purpose here: to get reputation for the sake of it, or to find answers and help others? :)

Comment: @TimMalone  The purpose is to get reputation to answer and upvote answers that I see.

Comment: For example, today I was wondering how to add a custom redirect to the wp_login_form().  I found what I was looking for here:

http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15633/how-can-i-redirect-user-after-entering-wrong-password

The answer I used was the one with 19 up votes BUT NOT the accepted answer.  I gave it an up-vote and it won't let me because I don't have 15 points.  So, went to comment thinking that would be "less abrasive" to the system and it wants 50 reputation points!!

Is my point being made here?  I MUST post my own questions to get points to interact with this place